# a 64 bit guest on a 32 bit host with 64 bit support

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, virtualbox, 32-bit

Can a 64bit Guest OS run on a 32bit Host OS if the processor is 64bit?
i'm running virtualbox on ubuntu 10.04 32bit

Answer (score 3):

[Yes, as long as these conditions are met:](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

1. Your processor is 64-bit with hardware virtualization support.
2. Hardware virtualization is enabled for the VM.
3. Obviously, the virtual machine is configured to be 64-bit.